# Loading screen stays on "Building editable for judgelm (pyproject.toml) ... /"

Tags: pip, anaconda

I was trying to install a LLM model to my pc via GitHub and Loading screen didn't change for a long time while installing the packages on anaconda command shell[image]. Also I didn't get any error as well.

I read pip upgrade could cause that. Then I upgraded pip but still this screen stays on the same line. [text](https://github.com/baaivision/JudgeLM)
you can check the LLM model via this link.